# C# Web Client : Cannot load the image in html when load the web page

Tags: c#

I am trying to load the html content using c# (To simulate php function - file_get_contents) using the following codes:

```
protected string file_get_contents(string fileName) 
{ 
  string sContents = string.Empty; 
  if (fileName.ToLower().IndexOf("http:") > -1) 
  { // URL 
   System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient(); 
   byte[] response = wc.DownloadData(fileName); 
   sContents = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response); 
  } else { 
   // Regular Filename 
   System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName); 
   sContents = sr.ReadToEnd(); 
   sr.Close(); 
  } 
 return sContents;
}
```

However, this does not load the image in the html when rendering the content. But when use PHP file_get_content, it does load the image in the html when rendering the content.

Anyone has any idea?

Comment: How are you rendering the content, and what does the img tag look like? Also, why are you using DownloadData and Encoding.ASCII rather than just DownloadString?

Comment: After reading the string, I just output the whole string into the webpage to view the content. The img tag is <img src="image/test.png" />. I followed http://www.devprise.com/2006/07/14/c-method-to-mimic-php-file_get_contents/.

Comment: I just tried DownloadString, seems like it does not load the image too unlike the php file_get_contents.

Comment: Have you tried saving the content to a file so that you can compare the contents with the source image?

Comment: Oh great, I tried. There is an error - HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable. &nbsp;Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. Seems like asp.net mvc treat it as its own url instead of loading from the remote source?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the documentation for [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), there shouldn't be a difference between using a [WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and this function to download the contents of an HTML page.
In both cases, you'll get a string like this:

```
string html = @"<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   Image: <img src=""/image/test.png"">
</body>
</html>";
```

Of course, `/image/test.png`  is relative to the URL you downloaded the HTML page from.
So if you download the HTML page from `http://www.example.com/test.html` and render the retrieved data at `http://www.yourdomain.net/foo/bar/qux.html` the image tag will refer to `http://www.yourdomain.net/image/test.png` rather than `http://www.example.com/image/test.png`.

You need to rewrite relative URLs to absolute ones before rendering the HTML page.
Have a look at the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) for this task.